# Floating two elements left and right and centering UL vertically?

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment, navigationbar

I am trying to create a navigation bar with image (floated left) and ul (floated right).

I can't seem to figure out how to get the ul to be vertically centered in the navigation bar so it is in the middle on the image on the far right.

Im looking to get something like this:

[image]
**CODE: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ysv3itqa**

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
                <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/553aa046e4b0fe84386ad100/t/55e5e602e4b0011b63cf4a51/1441129987213/applelogo.png" alt="">    
                <div class="outerNav">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Videos</li>
                        <li>Photos</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
                height: auto;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .top {
                background-color:black;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0px 0px;
                float:left;
                margin:0 auto;
            }

            .top img {
                width: 30px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                float:left;
            }

            .top .nav {
                border: 1px solid red;
                width: 50%;
                float:right;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .top .nav li {
                display: inline-block;
                color:white;
            }

            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I am trying to get a layout similar to the image above - where the image and nav bar are **Vertically** centered. @MarLen

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help

```
.top .nav {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:0px; /* reset top margin for ul */
}

.top .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    line-height:32px; /* height of your image */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without lineheight?

Answer (score 0):

Please update the following styles.

```
.top {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top .nav {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
    text-align: right; 
    margin: 0;}

.top .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    line-height:32px; /* height of your image */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a little gap below the image around 1px. Could that be due to the line height? Is there a way of doing it without line height?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/52/

HTML

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/553aa046e4b0fe84386ad100/t/55e5e602e4b0011b63cf4a51/1441129987213/applelogo.png" alt="">   
    </div> 
    <div class="outerNav">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Videos</li>
            <li>Photos</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.top {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: table;
}


.top img {
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.top .nav {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: right;
}

.top .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.outerNav {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30%;
}
```

**EDIT**
Maybe better remove width from nav like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/53/